# Scroll bar not coming on fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox and I want to display a vertical scrollbar if the data exceeds my fancybox pop-up but the scroll bar is not coming, instead background image enlarges upto text size. How can i do so?

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ajax_load('not','','1');

$("#notification-clip").fancybox({ 'titlePosition' : 'inside', 'transitionIn' : 'none', 'transitionOut' : 'none' });}); div style="display:none;" div id="not" /div /div
```

In the above div with id=not ,i am loading a page that contains a table of data fetched from database and i want to display a scroll bar when that data is greater than 10

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the code you are having problems with - a http://jsfiddle.net/ would be particularly nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">

    div.scroll {
       height: 200px;
       width: 300px;
       overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Apply this css to the div that contains the scrollable content . Or put the scrollable content in a div and give it the above css. 
Look at tall the options to overflow http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Also look at this css3 options 
http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Comment: <div id="not" ></div>        </div>this is the div in which i am loading a page using ajax taht page contains a table the code iam using for jquery is 

       $(document).ready(function() {

     ajax_load('not','<?php echo site_url('home/ajax_load'.'/'.'1');?>','1');

      $("#notification-clip").fancybox({

    'titlePosition'  : 'inside',

    'transitionIn'  : 'none',

    'transitionOut'  : 'none'

   });});                                 <area shape="rect" coords="3,65,91,87" id="notification-clip" href="#not"  title="" /> on click of this area i am calling that div with id=not

Comment: inside this div(id=not) add one more div and apply the above css for that